# Prophecy regarding Ciri: differences from the games?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-witcher

I started reading the Witcher books and obviously Ciri is headed to fulfill some kind of prophecy. However, that's also the plot of the last game. I understand that the games are a non-canonical continuation, but does that mean we don't get a satisfying conclusion to the last book? Please answer without spoiling it, I'm only interested if the prophecy's conclusion is the same as in the games.

Comment: My guess is people downvote it for some version of a "just read the book" reason.

Comment: I think that too, the thing is, before I read thousends of pages, I wanted to know if the geralt saga is going to actually have a buildup and a conclusion.

Comment: Um, well, yeah, it *definitely* has a conclusion. It's 5 novels and they don't just end by leaving everything hanging around unconcluded. If it concludes the angle of Ciri's prophecy in a way that you deem satisfying is something that you have to answer for yourself, though. So yeah, conclusive novel series.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach You have to understand that i have played the games. So slight spoiler from here : Ciri does fulfill the prophecy in the game, so if its supposed to be a continuation, that brings up questions. Does that mean that the prophecy is fulfiled twice ? so we have the book version and a game Version ? Then it wouldnt be a continouation (even if non cannonical) would it ? so there lays my question

Comment: @Meerkat I think that all you're really asking is whether there is a point to reading the book if you played the game. You're just asking it kinda weirdly, by presenting one single aspect of the story as the whole point of reading the book.

Comment: @Meerkat I've answered that question, of course its a spoiler, the book series as Cahir said comes to a conclusion. Also if you know Sapkowski's style, he likes to "vulgarize" things like prophecies, fairy tales etc - just check his version of "Snow White and 7 dwarves"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An important thing one must accept when reading The Witcher, is the fact that Sapkowski apparently did not aim to answer some question conclusively; you may see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131345/was-renfri-really-cursed-or-not) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106696/what-did-geralt-of-rivia-ask-for-his-third-wish) that questions asking about *what really happened* will not have definitive answers (the links I provided, as well as other Witcher questions here contain tons of **spoilers!**).

But I'll try to answer anyway.

In crudest terms, Ciri was meant to bear a male child who would be the "Avenger" (idk, that's what it said in Russian version). This person would save the inhabitants of her world from the White Frost. This is the reason why

- the Aen Elle,
- Vilgefortz of Roggeveen,
- Emhyr var Emreis
- and the Lodge of Sorceresses

seek her - each wants to manipulate her to conceive a child and then use it for their dirty stuff. Of them all, Vilgefortz was the coolest, because he simply wanted to

> impregnate her with a needle and then cut out her placenta

Anyways, you are right - we do get a somewhat dissatisfying conclusion - at least we could call it that way - because Ciri's part in the whole thing isn't explicitly stated (we do get a hint from Nimue in the *Lady of the Lake*, but that's a spoiler).

Games try to finish that storyline - there are 3 choices (to my knowledge), which are all somewhere on the Internet (spoilers, obviously).

It is perhaps enough to say that you get to decide whether the prophecy plays the way it was foreseen or not; maybe not in a way you'd expect it though.

Comment: Hope this helps, but feel free to poke me if you need clarification on something - I didn't write a wall of text only because I have a chem HW and only 1.5 hours to do it.

Comment: Thx m8. you really tried with the spoilers :D finally somebody answerd this. i will do the commitement of reading the rest of the books now.

Comment: @Meerkat  -  you're welcome. I thought I caught all the spoilers, but please forgive me if I didn't. Good luck with the books, wish I could erase my memory and read them again. P.S.: save *Season of Storms* and the games for later, if you can, though

Answer (score 3):

The original prophecy text is:

> "The Wolf's Blizzard approaches, the time of the sword and axe. The Time of the White Frost and White Light, the Time of Madness and Disdain, Tedd Deireadh, the Final Age. The world will perish amidst ice and be reborn with the new sun. Reborn of the Elder Blood, of Hen Ichaer, of a planted seed. A seed that will not sprout but burst into flames!"

That prophecy is strengthened by Falka's last words:

> "Avenger will be born from my blood! - she shouted - "Born from the cursed Elder Blood destroyer of nations and worlds! He will avenge my death!"

So it doesn't mention Ciri, but someone born from the "Elder Blood", or to be precisely a male offspring of someone having the "active" gene of Elder Blood, that is passed down among humans since Lara Dorren.

In the games, Ciri's destined role is to

> Defeat the White Frost, which is some sort of Eldritch Abomination that moves between words and freezing them.

The book is little bit anticlimactic:

> Yes, there is a "white frost" coming in the form of new ice age - the northern ports already started freezing during winter - but it will take a long, long time (Nimue thinks it will take about 3000 years).

So Ciri is not really destined to do anything, except possibly being mother (or maybe grandmother? Grand-grand mother?) to the "Destroyer of nations", but even that might be not true, since Ciri is not related by blood to Falka <sup>*</sup>.

Although, if she would marry

> emperor Emrys (yes, her father - but she doesn't remember him) - in the book he is looking for her and wants to marry her for political reasons

her offspring would indeed rule huge empire.

<sup>* Ciri is related directly to Riannon - daughter of Lara Dorren and human Cregennan of Lod. She was adopted by queen Cerro, second wife of king Vridank. Falka was the daughter from the first marriage and after bloody rebellion she killed her father, two stepbrothers and imprisoned pregnant Riannon. Falka was at that time pregnant as well and when she gave birth, she gave the child to Riannon, which (after Falka's death) has risen [all three children](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Houtborg_triplets) as her own. While wizards were able to find which child was Falka's, they kept the secret to avoid execution of a baby. 
 Falka's daughter, Adela, died at the age of 17 while helping sick during a plague</sup>

Comment: Not related by blood to Falka? I remember it to be the opposite!

Comment: +1 for "not destined to do anything" though. Her role is most often portrayed as passive.

Comment: Falka was the daughter of the first wife of king Vridank - queen Beatrix. Vridank dismissed Beatrix and married Cerro, that **adopted Riannon** (Ciri's great-great-greatmother) - daughter of Lara Dorren. Falka in bloody rebellion killed her father and two stepbrothers and imprisoned Riannon, then added her own child to Rianon's twins. Riannon risen all three children as their own, but we know for fact, that Falka's daughter died helping sick in the plague. So no - Ciri and Falka are not related by blood but by adoption.

Comment: Yet do we know for a fact which of three children was Falka's?

Comment: Yes we do.http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Adela

Comment: Page for Fiona [claims](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Fiona) that it was she who was the daughter of Falka. Still, Ciri descended from Amavet, you're right at that. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: @Gallifreian Ithat information is false (in story). Also Ciri comes in line from BOTH Rionna's children, because Amavet's granddaughter and Fiona's grandson married and gave birth to Calanthe, which also activated the Elder Blood gene - one that Falka didn't have.

Comment: Nice catch about both children, I completely forgot this one. Finally, everything is in place.